# Werkzeug Response Object not Iterable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, werkzeug

Am using **Google app engines** webapps **run_wsgi_app** utility to wrap my flask app instance, I figured it's a webapp issue since with flask only it works fine. It happens after a POST request on an API route

```
ERROR    2013-10-14 18:18:53,862 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/synod/Desktop/MedApp/GAE-app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    run_wsgi_app(app)
  File "/usr/lib/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/usr/lib/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 118, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    for data in result:
  File "/home/synod/Desktop/MedApp/GAE-app/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 508, in next
    return self._next()
  File "/home/synod/Desktop/MedApp/GAE-app/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 789, in iter_encoded
    for item in self.response:
TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable

INFO     2013-10-14 18:18:53,869 module.py:599] default: "POST /api/betaMember/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -

@app.route('/api/betaMember/', methods=['POST'])
def betaMember():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/json':
        abort(400)

    if not 'email' in request.json:
        abort(400)

    if not 'name' in request.json:
        abort(400)

    name = request.json.get('name')
    email = request.json.get('email')

    # person = Person(email = email,name = name)            
    # person.put()

    return make_response(jsonify({"OK": "Data Saved"}), 201)
```

Comment: Probably a conflict between your Flask and Werkzeug versions. Which versions are you using for these packages?

Comment: Werkzeug ==  0.9.4, flask == 0.10.1

Comment: Am using the latest of both versions. Flask v0.10.1 depends on werkzeug v0.9.4

Comment: You don't seem to be running Werkzeug 0.9.4. Line 789 of _wrappers.py_ from your stacktrace does not match with the source code for that release.

Comment: @Miguel OK, just checked, **werkzeug** is 0.9.1..even after pip install -U, that fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: For avoiding things like these I created the [gae-init](https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init) which has among other cool things all the latest and greatest versions of 3rd party libraries and works out of the box!